# JQuery - process elements as they are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute a js code at the head of the page and have this code be watching for any elements that might be loaded from the html, as soon as they are available, instead of waiting for the page to complete loading. Is that possible?

My case:

I want to hide some elements from a page dynamically. So far, I ve been doing this at the `$(window).ready(...)` function, but the side effect is that the elements are shown for a second before this function kicks in. I would like to catch these elements as soon as they are loaded and ready to be shown and not have to wait til the whole page gets loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use css rules to hide them instead of using script

Comment: even though that answers my particular case, it doesnt answer the more generic question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid the effect you are describing you could just reverse your logic and initially hide all elements with css you then show

Comment: Of course this works but what if I need to do something else like change the text or something?

Comment: you show and manipulate as you like with javascript on dom ready, so you avoid the effect of seeing stuff for a second

Comment: Great thanks! If you want you can add that in the answer too

Answer (score 2):

You can hide elements "by default" with CSS class and then, when page is ready, remove class on elements you want to show.

**Very simple** example:

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
  <li class="hidden to-be-shown">Element A</li>
  <li class="hidden">Element B</li>
  <li class="hidden to-be-shown">Element C</li>
  <li class="hidden to-be-shown">Element D</li>
  <li class="hidden">Element E</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$(function () {
    $('.to-be-shown').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/css3o3my/).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into `$(document).load()` which fires when the page is loaded as opposed to `$(document).ready()` which fires when the page is rendered

Answer (score 0):

Well simple method is to do it with CSS(display:none)
But i you want to use jquery you can try

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //Code
});
```

Hope this helps